# How to use exactly the same google maps style and PIN locations?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use the same style and PIN locations for a client's website map just like this : `http://www.bekaerttextiles.com/en`

But I can't see anything related to map except google maps apis file.
How is it generating this map?
There's not any json or javascript related to PIN locations and their lat-long. nor the white style of map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design your map by adding `styles` to the config object (The second parameter in `new google.maps.Map`). See the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

Note: The marker icon is a private image so you should create one by your own. (http://www.bekaerttextiles.com/build/web/images/marker.svg)

The styles you are looking for are:

```js
[
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#F2F0E9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And the live example:

```js
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: uluru,
    styles: styles
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
}

var styles = [
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#F2F0E9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```

http://output.jsbin.com/fiqapa